# How to use complex data object as list in DMN Diagram by Enterprise Architecture

Tags: enterprise-architect, dmn

We are gonna draw a DMN diagram for entities like the image below. Travel entities include a list(many to one relation) of Persons.
[image]

There is a problem with designing a DMN with Enterprise Architecture for such a system:
It is not possible to use the data type defined as person in travel and it must be defined in travel. We would like some think like (Person : Person) but as far as I know we haven’t got complex type in EA.

[image]

[image]

After all we can’t add list data in dataset dialog

Comment: We have got the same problem, EA support string,int,date type.

Comment: A `Person` is a `Travel`? Can I live where you live?

Comment: @qwerty_so Look at the diagram! I think so he/she wanted to show Travel has got many persons. Please focus on the main problem, how we can add a list of persons in travel object.

Comment: I'm not in DMN so I can't contribute. The above is a funny observation. You need a laugh from time to time. Just use your cheek muscles :-/